# Laravel spatie , assignrole() is not working when team_id is used?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

this is modified seeder code

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->get();
        $role = Role::where('id', 1)->get();
        echo $role;
        $user->assignRole([$role->id]);
```

this is the output

```
[{"id":1,"team_id":2,"name":"Admin","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2023-01-10T06:40:56.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-01-10T06:40:56.000000Z"}]
   Exception 

  Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:969
    965▕      */
    966▕     public function __get($key)
    967▕     {
    968▕         if (! in_array($key, static::$proxies)) {
  ➜ 969▕             throw new Exception("Property [{$key}] does not exist on this collection instance.");
    970▕         }
    971▕ 
    972▕         return new HigherOrderCollectionProxy($this, $key);
    973▕     }

  1   database/seeders/CreateAdminUserSeeder.php:32
      Illuminate\Support\Collection::__get("id")

      +22 vendor frames 
  24  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

you can see that the id is there on echo but I cant assign the role using its id

this only happed when teams set to trues in config file.

I am missing something or is it a bug?(highly doubt it )

Answer (score 1):

`$role = Role::where('id', 1)->get();` returns a collection of roles

**Instead you can either do:**

```
$role = Role::find(1);
```

**or**

```
$role = Role::where('id', 1)->first();
```

---

**To clear the cache when adding new permissions/roles run the following artisan commands:**

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

**For reference you can run the following to clear everything cached:**

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: thanks for answering but it did not work
```
{"id":1,"team_id":2,"name":"Admin","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2023-01-10T06:40:56.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-01-10T06:40:56.000000Z"}
   Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist 

  There is no role with id `1`.

  at vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Exceptions/RoleDoesNotExist.php:16
     12▕     }
     13▕ 
     14▕     public static function withId(int $roleId)
     15▕     {
  ➜  16▕         return new static("There is no role with id `{$roleId}`.");
     17▕     }
     18▕ }
     19▕ 

   ```

Comment: You need to clear your config/cache when creating a new role/permission, check my modified answer, and it works for you, kindly mark it as complete (check mark)